Neo4j Cluster: Random Transaction Delays with Raft Replication Errors in Logs
We are experiencing intermittent delays (5 to 30 seconds) with random transactions in our Neo4j (4.4) distributed cluster. The cluster does not appear to be under system pressure (no IO waits, CPU usage is low, and network pings between nodes are stable).
The logs show the following during the issue:
INFO  [c.n.c.c.r.RaftReplicator] [datab/50f25d2b] Replication attempt 2 to leader RaftMemberId{442s04bc2}: DistributedOperation{content=ReplicatedTransaction{tx=PhysicalTransactionRepresentation[timeStarted:1726503109163, latestCommittedTxWhenStarted:2393973872, timeCommitted:1726503109164, lease:161, additionalHeader:[], commands.length:1, databaseId=DatabaseId{50f25d3b}}, globalSession=GlobalSession{sessionId=44deb162-c756-4625-8bb9-cf962se30d1c9, owner=RaftMemberId{44204bc2}}, operationId=LocalOperationId{localSessionId=25, sequenceNumber=113719}}

Additionally, with debug logging enabled, we see entries like this:
DEBUG [c.n.c.c.s.CommandApplicationProcess] [datab/50f25d2b] Skipped an invalid distributed operation: DistributedOperation{content=ReplicatedTransaction{tx=PhysicalTransactionRepresentation[timeStarted:1726503109163, latestCommittedTxWhenStarted:2393973872, timeCommitted:1726503109164, lease:161, additionalHeader:[0, 0, 0, 0, -114, -73, -87, -22], commands.length:1, databaseId=DatabaseId{50f25d2b}}, globalSession=GlobalSession{sessionId=44deb162-c756-4625-8bb9-cf962e30d1c9, owner=RaftMemberId{44204bc2}}, operationId=LocalOperationId{localSessionId=25, sequenceNumber=113719}}. Session tracker state: GlobalSessionTrackerState{sessionTrackers={RaftMemberId{f511735d}=LocalSessionTracker{globalSessionId=b684d77e-e10a-4ea7-b30e-160ff12a29a2, lastSequenceNumberPerSession={0=225, 1=177, 2=433, 3=84, 4=51, 5=194, 6=72, 7=336, 8=192, 9=37}}, ....

INFO  [c.n.c.c.s.CommandApplicationProcess] [datab/50f25d2b] BatchSize{min=1.0, max=8.0, avg=1.0878906249999978, count=4096}

We've reviewed system metrics and haven't found any obvious resource constraints.
What could be causing these random transaction delays, and how can we further diagnose or resolve the issue based on the log details?
